# What’s the opcode chain for sending ethereum from a smart contract?

Tags: evm, opcode

Simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer anywhere.
I know `CALL` is used and sometimes `CALLER`, but I don’t have any idea on how `msg.sender.call.value(100)` would be performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EVM is a stack machine, so arguments to instructions are put on a stack before the instruction is executed. You can find the parameters each instruction takes as well as their order in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) or in your favorite EVM implementation, e.g. [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/vm.py#L658) for the `CALL` instruction:

```
gas, to, value, meminstart, meminsz, memoutstart, memoutsz = \
    stk.pop(), stk.pop(), stk.pop(), stk.pop(), stk.pop(), stk.pop(), stk.pop()
```

Therefore, a `CALL` needs the available gas on top of the stack, then the destination address, value, input memory offset etc.

A valid instruction chain could simply look like this:

```
PUSH32 <memoutsz>
PUSH32 <memoutstart>
PUSH32 <meminsz>
PUSH32 <meminstart>
PUSH32 <value>
PUSH20 <to>
PUSh32 <gas>
CALL
```

**Edit:**
`meminstart` and `meminsz` define the input data for the call, which usually are the function arguments for the called contract. `meminstart` is the offset in the memory and `meminsz` is the size of the data. If you just want to send ether to a contract, you can set both of them to 0.

`memoutstart` and `memoutsz` define an area in the memory where the return data of the call is stored at (if there is any).

Comment: What’s `meminstart` `meminsz` `memoutstart` `memoutsz`?

Comment: @user2284570 Added an explanation to my answer.